# Single line with multiple colors based on time in using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to generate a graph like I have shown here 
[Single line with multiple colors over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvzUE.jpg)

The X axis will be time series . Can anyone suggest a JQuery plugin to generate such a graph ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try below chart and change as per your requirement

```js
 
var graph = (function(){
  var urgentTitle = "Urgent",
      $graph = $('.graph'),
      $barContainer = $graph.find('.graph-bars'),
      $markers = $('.markers'),
      $graphTitles = $('.graph-titles'),
      max = null,
      limit = null;
  var init = function(data){ 
    max = getMaxValue(data);
    limit = max + Math.ceil(max * 0.05);
    $barContainer.empty();
    $markers.empty();
    $graphTitles.empty();
    $('#urgent-title').text(urgentTitle);
 
    setMarkers($markers, limit);
    if (data.length) buildTeamRows($barContainer, $graphTitles, data, limit);
    else buildUserRows($barContainer, $graphTitles, data, limit);
  };
 
  // return a values percentage in relation to the limit
  var getPercentage = function(value, limit) {
      return value / limit * 100 + "%";
  };
  
  var getMaxValue = function(data) {
    var largest = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    if (data.length) {
      for (x=0;x<data.length;x++) {
        sum = data[x].active + data[x].newCount + data[x].newFromBatch;
        if (sum > largest) {
          largest = sum;
        }
      }
    } else {
      largest = Math.max(data.active, data.newCount, data.newFromBatch);
    }
    return largest;
  };
 
  var setMarkers = function($selector, limit) {
    var increment = limit / 5;
    var value = 0;
    var values = [];
    var leftOffset = 0;
    // Create array of marker values
    while(value < limit) {
      values.push(Math.round(value));
      value += increment;
    }
    values.push(limit);
    for (var x=0;x<values.length;x++) {
      var $markerTmpl = $('<div class="marker"><span class="marker-number"></span></div>');
      leftOffset = getPercentage(values[x], limit);
      $markerTmpl.css({ 'left': leftOffset }).find('.marker-number').text(values[x]);
      $selector.append($markerTmpl);
    }
    $selector.addClass('loaded');
  };
 
  //Build each individual graph based on selector, data, and max value
  var buildTeamRows = function($barSelector, $titleSelector, data, limit) {
    var percentage;
    // Loop through data
    for (var x=0;x<data.length;x++) {
      var titleClass = null;
      var titleCount = 0;
      var $graphBar = $('<div class="graph-bar"></div>')
          .attr('id', 'userGraph-' + data[x].userId);
      $barSelector.append($graphBar);
      // Render each fragment
      renderFragment($graphBar, 'urgent', data[x].urgent, limit);
      renderFragment($graphBar, 'active', data[x].active - data[x].urgent, limit);
      renderFragment($graphBar, 'newCount', data[x].newCount, limit);
      renderFragment($graphBar, 'newFromBatch', data[x].newFromBatch, limit);
 
      // Calculate largest fragment value
      var largest = 0;
      $.each(data[x], function(index, value){
        if ($.isNumeric(value)){
          if (value > largest) {
            largest = value;
            titleClass = index;
            titleCount = value;
          }
        }
      });
      // If Active is greatest value, Check if urgent portion of active is greater than active
      if (titleClass === 'active' && data[x].urgent >= (data[x].active - data[x].urgent)) {
        titleClass = 'urgent';
        titleCount = data[x].urgent;
      }
    // Render row meta-data
    var $titleSet = $('<div class="graph-title"><div class="graph-title-name"></div><div class="graph-title-count"></div></div>');
    $titleSet.find('.graph-title-name').text(data[x].userName);
    $titleSet.find('.graph-title-count').addClass(titleClass).text(titleCount);
    $titleSelector.append($titleSet);
    }
  };
 
  var renderFragment = function($selector, type, value, limit) {
    var $rowFragmentTmpl = $('<div class="graph-bar-fragment"></div>');
    var percentage = getPercentage(value, limit);
    $rowFragmentTmpl.attr('data-value', value);
    $selector.append($rowFragmentTmpl.addClass(type));
    setTimeout(function(){
      $rowFragmentTmpl.css({'width': percentage});
    }, 1);
  };
 
  var buildUserRows = function($barSelector, $titleSelector, data, limit) {
    renderUserRow($barSelector, $titleSelector, 'urgent', data.urgent, limit, urgentTitle);
    renderUserRow($barSelector, $titleSelector, 'active', data.active, limit, 'Active');
    renderUserRow($barSelector, $titleSelector, 'newCount', data.newCount, limit, 'New');
    renderUserRow($barSelector, $titleSelector, 'newFromBatch', data.newFromBatch, limit, 'New From Batch');
  };
 
  var renderUserRow = function($barSelector, $titleSelector, type, value, limit, title) {
    var percentage = getPercentage(value, limit);
    var $graphBar = $('<div class="graph-bar graph-bar-single"></div>').attr({'id' : 'userGraph-' + type, 'data-value': value});
    $barSelector.append($graphBar);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $graphBar.css({'width': percentage}).addClass(type);
    },1);
 
    var $titleSet = $('<div class="graph-title"><div class="graph-title-name"></div><div class="graph-title-count"></div></div>');
    $titleSet.find('.graph-title-name').text(title);
    $titleSet.find('.graph-title-count').addClass(type).text(value);
    $titleSelector.append($titleSet);
  };
 
  return {
    init: init
  }
 
})();


// Document ready

$(function(){
   // Dummy Data
  var dataSet = [
    {
      active: 5,
      newCount: 4,
      newFromBatch: 40,
      urgent: 1,
      userId: "molly",
      userName: "Molly"
    },
    {
      active: 21,
      newCount: 2,
      newFromBatch: 5,
      urgent: 10,
      userId: "jack",
      userName: "Jack"
    },  
    {
      active: 25,
      newCount: 4,
      newFromBatch: 3,
      urgent: 20,
      userId: "tracy",
      userName: "Tracy"
    },  
    {
      active: 10,
      newCount: 24,
      newFromBatch: 4,
      urgent: 2,
      userId: "nolan",
      userName: "Nolan"
    },  
  ];
 
  var dataSingle = {
      active: 25,
      newCount: 4,
      newFromBatch: 3,
      urgent: 20,
      userId: "ryan",
      userName: "Ryan Scofield"
  };
 
  // Initialize Graph
  graph.init(dataSet);
 
  $('#teamGraph').on('click', function(e){
    graph.init(dataSet);
  });
 
  $('#userGraph').on('click', function(e){
    graph.init(dataSingle);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Opportunity Graphs */
.graph-titles {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.graph-title {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.graph-title-name {
  float: left;
}

.graph-title-count {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.graph {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
}

.graph-bar {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.graph-bar-fragment {
  width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s ease-in;
}

.graph-bar-single {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s ease-in;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.graph-bar-fragment:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.urgent {
  background: #c9575e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9575e 0%, #c12e41 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #c9575e), color-stop(100%, #c12e41));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9575e 0%, #c12e41 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c9575e 0%, #c12e41 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c9575e 0%, #c12e41 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c9575e 0%, #c12e41 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c9575e', endColorstr='#c12e41',GradientType=0 );
}

.active {
  background: #d6ac6e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d6ac6e 0%, #cc9e52 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d6ac6e), color-stop(100%, #cc9e52));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d6ac6e 0%, #cc9e52 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d6ac6e 0%, #cc9e52 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d6ac6e 0%, #cc9e52 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d6ac6e 0%, #cc9e52 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6ac6e', endColorstr='#cc9e52',GradientType=0 );
}

.newCount {
  background: #6db683;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6db683 0%, #569b6d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #6db683), color-stop(100%, #569b6d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6db683 0%, #569b6d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6db683 0%, #569b6d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6db683 0%, #569b6d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6db683 0%, #569b6d 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db683', endColorstr='#569b6d',GradientType=0 );
}

.newFromBatch {
  background: #7f8cc4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7f8cc4 0%, #6477ac 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #7f8cc4), color-stop(100%, #6477ac));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7f8cc4 0%, #6477ac 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7f8cc4 0%, #6477ac 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7f8cc4 0%, #6477ac 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7f8cc4 0%, #6477ac 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7f8cc4', endColorstr='#6477ac',GradientType=0 );
}

.markers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
}

.markers.loaded {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.marker {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2em;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.marker-number {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: .5em;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.marker:last-child .marker-number {
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: .5em;
}

.graph-key {
  margin: 20px 0 0 210px;
}

.graph-key-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.graph-key-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph-container">
  <div class="graph-titles">
   <!-- Populated -->
  </div>
 <div class="graph">
   
    <div class="graph-bars">
      <!-- Populated -->
    </div>
  
    <div class="markers">
    <!-- Populated -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="graph-key">
    <div class="graph-key-item">
      <span class="graph-key-dot urgent"></span><span id="urgent-title">Urgent</span>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-key-item">
      <span class="graph-key-dot active"></span><span>Active</span>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-key-item">
      <span class="graph-key-dot newCount"></span><span>New</span>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-key-item">
      <span class="graph-key-dot newFromBatch"></span><span>New From Batch</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="teamGraph">Team Graph</button>
<button id="userGraph">User Graph</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: Ok, But one doubt. Here how can I show time series in X axis.?

Comment: @SanoojM you removed accepted answer, let me try :(

Comment: sorry for removing the accepted, I didn't notice the x axis first time

Answer (score 0):

Try below chart and change value as per your requirement

```js
var chart = new Chartist.Bar('#chart01',
  {
    labels: ['C-Level', 'Executive', 'Director', 'Manager', 'Professional', 'Other'],
    series: [
      [3,9,5,8,4,2],
      [2,8,4,19,25,6],
      [2,16,6,53,57,12]
    ]
  },
  {
    stackBars: true,
    seriesBarDistance: 10,
    reverseData: false,
    horizontalBars: true,
    low: 0,
    fullWidth: true,
    chartPadding: {
      right: 30,
      left: 30
    },
    axisX: {
      showGrid: true,
      showLabel: true
    },
    axisY: {
      showGrid: false,
      showLabel: true,
      offset: 60,
      onlyInteger: true,
      labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
        return value;
      }
    }
});



$('#chart01').on('click', '.ct-chart-bar .ct-labels foreignobject', function(evt) {
  var index = $(this).index();
  var label = $(this).find('span.ct-label').text();
  graphClicked(index, label, null);
});

$('#chart01').on('mouseover', '.ct-chart-bar .ct-series-a line, .ct-chart-bar .ct-series-b line, .ct-chart-bar .ct-series-c line', function(evt) {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).closest('.ct-chart-bar').find('.ct-labels foreignobject:nth-child('+(index+1)+') span').addClass('hover');
});

$('#chart01').on('mouseleave', '.ct-chart-bar .ct-series-a line, .ct-chart-bar .ct-series-b line, .ct-chart-bar .ct-series-c line', function(evt) {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).closest('.ct-chart-bar').find('.ct-labels foreignobject:nth-child('+(index+1)+') span').removeClass('hover');
});

$('#chart01').on('click', '.ct-chart-bar .ct-series-a line, .ct-chart-bar .ct-series-b line, .ct-chart-bar .ct-series-c line', function(evt) {
  var index = $(this).index();
  var label = $(this).closest('.ct-chart-bar').find('.ct-labels foreignobject:nth-child('+(index+1)+') span').text();
  var value = $(this).attr('ct:value');
  graphClicked(index, label, value);
});

function graphClicked(index, label, value) {
  console.log('---');
  console.log('index:', index);
  console.log('label:', label);
  alert('Index: '+index+', Label: '+label+', Value: '+value);
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.chart-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.center-link {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.ct-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
}

.ct-series-a .ct-line {
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.ct-series-a .ct-line, .ct-series-a .ct-point, .ct-series-a .ct-bar {
  stroke: #5b9bd5;
}

.ct-series-b .ct-line {
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.ct-series-b .ct-line, .ct-series-b .ct-point, .ct-series-b .ct-bar {
  stroke: #ed7d31;
}

.ct-series-c .ct-line {
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.ct-series-c .ct-line, .ct-series-c .ct-point, .ct-series-c .ct-bar {
  stroke: #a5a5a5;
}

.chart-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.key {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  color: #555;
  padding: 0 30px 0 90px;
}
.key .key-element {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.key .key-element:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
}
.key .key-element.key-series-a:before {
  background-color: #5b9bd5;
}
.key .key-element.key-series-b:before {
  background-color: #ed7d31;
}
.key .key-element.key-series-c:before {
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
}

.ct-chart-bar.ct-horizontal-bars .ct-label.ct-horizontal.ct-end {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.ct-chart-bar .ct-labels foreignobject {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ct-chart-bar .ct-labels foreignobject span {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ct-chart-bar .ct-labels foreignobject span:hover, .ct-chart-bar .ct-labels foreignobject span.hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.ct-chart-bar .ct-series line {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.7/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.7/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="chart-wrapper">

  <h4>Click on the bars to get their index, label and value</h4>
  <div id="chart01" class="ct-chart ct-chart01 ct-octave"></div>
  <div class="key">
    <div class="key-element key-series-a">Account Topic Score</div>
    <div class="key-element key-series-b">#Unique Contacts</div>
    <div class="key-element key-series-c">#Interactions</div>
  </div>
</div>
```